# @XmlVariableNode ignores the second property if used twice

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo, moxy

I have to create POJOs so that I can generate XML using JAXB for the below XML *(Just a sample because child elements may go beyond 40)*.

Here, important thing to note is that I cannot declare these elements as properties in POJO because I won't be knowing the elements name.

```
<User>
    <FirstName>Mahendra</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Singh</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Dhoni</LastName>
    <Organization>
         <Name>Electronics</Name>
         <id>elc001</id>
    </Organization>
    <Manager>
         <Name>Sourabh</Name>
         <id>emp_001</id>
    </Manager>
</User>
```

I have created POJO for above XML as:

**Fields1.java** : For elements having value only.

```
public class Fields1 
{
    @XmlTransient
    public String fieldName1;

    @XmlValue
    public String value;

    //  getter,setter
}
```

**Fields2.java** : For elements having child elements.

```
public class Fields2 
{
    @XmlTransient
    public String fieldName2;

    @XmlElement(name="NAME")
    public String name;

    @XmlElement(name="ID")
    public String id;

    //  getter,setter
}
```

**User.java** : Root element class

```
public class User
{

    @XmlVariableNode("fieldName1")
    public List<Fields1> fields1;

    @XmlVariableNode("fieldName2")
    public List<Fields2> fields2;

    //  getter, setter
}
```

Here, @XmlVariableNode is helping me to generate elements name dynamically. 
1. But, it only works fine if there is only single property 
2. and if, there are two properties then it just works for the first one and ignores the next.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, multiple `@XmlVariableNode`s in the same class are not possible. EclipseLink's documentation states:

> Since this [@XmlVariableNode] makes use of the any logic during unmarshal and MOXy only
>   handles one Any mapping on a class if a class makes use of the
>   XmlVariableNode annotation then that class can not have XmlAnyElement
>   annotations or any other variables that would cause AnyObject or
>   AnyCollection mappings to be created.

(Source: [EclipseLink/DesignDocs/406697](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/DesignDocs/406697))

You might be able to solve your problem by using nested `@XmlVariableNode`s:

```java
public class TopLevelField {

    @XmlTransient
    public String fieldName;

    @XmlVariableNode("fieldName")
    public List<NestedField> fields;

    // ...
}
```

```java
public class NestedField {

    @XmlTransient
    public String fieldName;

    @XmlValue
    public String value;

    // ...
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    @XmlVariableNode("fieldName")
    public List<TopLevelField> fields;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response bro and as you suggested has already been achieved that you know too. But, what I want here is how to make that @XmlVariableNode work for both elements or if there is any alternative for this annotation. so that, I can get both kind of elements (with only value and with child elements).